# undefined reference to > `std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned long)'

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-reference

I have the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
        ostringstream oss;
        unsigned long k = 5;
        oss << k;
}
```

Compiled with the following parameters:

> /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -I/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/include
> -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -lstdc++ b.cpp

Got the following output:

> /tmp/cclRSXGV.o: In function `main': b.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to` std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned long)'

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What is needed to get it to compile and link correctly?

Using GNU gcc 10.2.0.

Comment: `g++ -Wall -std=c++11` works for me -- try specifying `-std=c++11`

Comment: [Do check if it works like the one given in this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977858/why-do-i-get-undefined-reference-errors-compiling-a-simple-c-program-with-gc)

Comment: works for me - there any other error / warning messages ?

Comment: @PriyadarshSS, please note that I'm using g++ and not gcc, and I've also specified -lstdc++ so I've basically tried both options available.

Comment: @lostbard unfortunately, no other error or warnings, even with -Wall and -std=c++11

Comment: @wcochran even with those flags, I don't get any other error or warning... it just throws the error mentioned in the question. I've tried this on multiple computers... all giving the same error... got this with gcc 9.2.0 and gcc 10.2.0...

Comment: what linux OS are you using and how was gcc/g++ installed ?

Comment: @lostbard CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch

Comment: GCC installed via ../gcc-10.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0 --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-dssi --enable-libgcj-multifile --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux && make install-strip

Comment: sounds like perhaps a broken gcc tool chain  - how about compiling a simple program: #include <iostreams> int main() { std::cout << "test\n"; return 0; }

Comment: Turns out, it will compile with: /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -I/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/include -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -lstdc++ b.cpp /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.a  I just need to specific the exact libstdc++.a after the cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it will compile with:

```
/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -I/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/include -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 b.cpp -lstdc++ /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.a
```

I just need to specific the exact libstdc++.a after the cpp file. While I worried that this would cause libstdc++.a to be statically linked, I don't think it will. Static linking requires `-static-libstdc++`.

Still can't figure out why I need to specify libstdc++.a when my earlier gcc (4.4.7) didn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify what libraries to link the order matters. In this order

```
-lstdc++ b.cpp
```

`libstdc++` will not resolve any symbols in `b.cpp`. Specify the library afterwords:

```
b.cpp -lstdc++
```

Comment: still gets the same error for both cases: `b.cpp -lstdc++` and `-lstdc++ b.cpp` ... this is looking more and more like my tool chain aren't properly installed or configured...

Comment: There may be something else awry, but it important to specify libraries in the order so that they resolve symbols from modules to the left of the on the command line.