# Why does g++ require libstdc++.a? Why is it not the default?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65739215/2191695), and the solution was to explicitly pass libstdc++.a to g++, like the following:

```
/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -I/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/include -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 b.cpp /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.a
```

**My question: Why do I need to explicitly pass libstdc++.a? How can I make it automatic so that libstdc++.a is used by default? How can I find the answer to the two questions?**

The test code:

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
        ostringstream oss;
        unsigned long k = 5;
        oss << k;
}
```

Compiled with the following parameters:

```
/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -I/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/include -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 -lstdc++ b.cpp
```

Got the following output:

```
/tmp/cclRSXGV.o: In function main': b.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using GNU gcc 10.2.0, installed with the following:

```
../gcc-10.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0 --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-dssi --enable-libgcj-multifile --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux && make install-strip
```

Already had GNU gcc 4.4.7 installed by default at /usr, and GNU gcc 9.2.0 at /usr/local/gcc-9.2.0

Running `/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -v b.cpp` produces the following:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../gcc-10.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0 --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-dssi --enable-libgcj-multifile --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE b.cpp -quiet -dumpbase b.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase b -version -o /tmp/ccJiMH6j.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 10.2.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-redhat-linux
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../../include/c++/10.2.0/backward
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/include
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 10.2.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 410dfe626634fcd13dbcedee05209c5e
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccUyoUr2.o /tmp/ccJiMH6j.s
GNU assembler version 2.35 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.35
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/:/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/:/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/:/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/:/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/collect2 -plugin /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccfGN6NK.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crti.o /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/../../.. /tmp/ccUyoUr2.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/local/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUyoUr2.o: in function `main':
b.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/local/bin/ld: b.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: g++ supports multiple standard libraries, and even cross-compiling and the like.  These require specifying a custom standard library to link.  I don't know how to make g++ defsult to using a specific one, so I'll let someone else answer that.

Comment: You should not need any of these `-I`, `-L` or `-l` flags for a correctly configured compiler. The only one you may need is `-Wl,-rpath`.  Run `/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/bin/g++ -v b.cpp` and post the output.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I've posted the output from compiling with `-v`... What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have any files named libstdc++.so.6 in `/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10.2.0/` or in `/usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64/`? What does it contain?

Comment: libstdc++.a and libstdc++.so are all there in /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64 .. that's why it works when I call g++ with /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.a

Comment: I think the program is incorrect, it should have `#include <ostream>` as well

Comment: Are you sure this program generated that output? It says `undefined reference to std::cout` but you do not use `std::cout`

Comment: @M.M, including ostream makes no difference. The problem is definitely not in the source code. It's most likely a problem with the toolchain. As to what is exact wrong, that is the question asked.

Comment: Incorrect includes can cause this problem

Comment: @M.M, cout is a mix up of output. I've tried this a few times with different code and the -v output produced was much later, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: @M.M I'm not the only person having this problem.... Same problem on multiple machines... different programmers... but always the same problem.... libstdc++.a needs to be explicitly included for linking, despite the linker already getting -lstdc++ as can be seen in the -v output.

Comment: Unless someone who can reproduce the problem themself and also fix it sees this question -- you'll need to do your best to help debug it, part of which is having a correct program, and also pasting the exact output of `g++ -v` for the program shown

Answer (score 6):

By default g++ links against the dynamic libstdc++ library (libstdc++.so). By passing libstdc++.a explicitly you're linking against the static counterpart. You could achieve the same end result with `-static-libstdc++`.

Both static and dynamic linking against libstdc++ should work. Your issue could be possibly caused by building or installing GCC incorrectly (e.g. applying an incorrect patch, or mixing include files from different GCC builds).

To investigate, produce object file `b.o` by adding `-c` to your g++ command line, and preprocessed source `b.ii` by adding `-E -o b.ii`. Use `nm -u b.o` to get mangled names of undefined symbols (add `-C` to demangle). You'll see that mangled name of the missing symbol is `_ZNSolsEm`. Try to grep the missing symbol in the list of symbols defined by libstdc++ (`nm -D --defined-only /usr/local/gcc-10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so`). If it is missing from the library, the issue is that the included files expect the library to provide those template instantiations, while the actual library does not.

If you look in `b.ii`, you'll find that it declares the corresponding `extern template` towards the end:

```cpp
  extern template class basic_ostringstream<char>;
```

If you look into `sstream.tcc` file from gcc install tree that this line comes from, you'll see it's guarded by `#if _GLIBCXX_EXTERN_TEMPLATE`. The definition of this macro is in `c++config.h`, and is set depending on `--enable-extern-template` option at libstdc++ configuration time. If the library is built with `--disable-extern-template`, it will not provide those template instantiations.